# SQL and XML files compare in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, compare

I am using Eclipse 3.5 for my java application development. I see eclipse can compare Java, text, and property files. When I open Sql or xml for comparison it just opens in Text Compare.
I am having trouble comparing large xml files.I searched all over but couldn't find any valid information.

I installed Web Tools Platform project in my eclipse, but it didn't work either.